# Read tif image metadata in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exif

What I want to do is read metadata from a tiff image from nodejs, this image come from a scientific device and has some specific information. In linux I have installed [exiftool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/exiftool.1p.html) and it retrive correctly all metadata of that image.

The problem is in nodejs, I have tried many modules but nobody of them works, for example I've installed exif-parser that is one of the most popular and tried to do this:

```
var buffer = readSync('./example_image.tif');
var parser = require('exif-parser').create(buffer);
var result = parser.parse();
```

But appears this error: "JPEG section offset"

Comment: First result from google "exif tool js": https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Comment: @spectatorx: see https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js/issues/151

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem using the library [exif-vendored](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exiftool-vendored). Consulnting the documentation I've seen that there's the possibility to specify a certain "custom" tag to read. I've tried all exif libraries but I think that's the only that can read custom tag from a TIFF file